# Is it possible to specialize on a static lifetime?

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime, specialization

I want to specialize `&'static str` from `&'a str`:

```rust
use std::borrow::Cow;

struct MyString {
    inner: Cow<'static, str>,
}

impl From<&'static str> for MyString {
    fn from(x: &'static str) -> Self {
        MyString {
            inner: Cow::Borrowed(x),
        }
    }
}

impl<T: Into<String>> From<T> for MyString {
    fn from(x: T) -> Self {
        MyString {
            inner: Cow::Owned(x.into()),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    match MyString::from("foo").inner {
        Cow::Borrowed(..) => (),
        _ => {
            panic!();
        }
    }

    let s = String::from("bar");
    match MyString::from(s.as_ref()).inner {
        Cow::Owned(..) => (),
        _ => {
            panic!();
        }
    }

    match MyString::from(String::from("qux")).inner {
        Cow::Owned(..) => (),
        _ => {
            panic!();
        }
    }
}
```

The gist is that `MyString` stores a statically-allocated string literal as a `&'static str` and all other strings as a `String`. This allows `MyString` to avoid having a lifetime parameter—i.e., `MyString<'a>`, which is critical for my API, all while allowing the caller to pass in any kind of string and have `MyString` automatically do the correct thing.

The problem is that the code doesn't compile:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::From<&'static str>` for type `MyString`:
  --> src/main.rs:15:1
   |
7  | impl From<&'static str> for MyString {
   | ------------------------------------ first implementation here
...
15 | impl<T: Into<String>> From<T> for MyString {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation for `MyString`
```

Is there any trick that allows me to do what I want? If not, is lifetime specialization something that Rust will ever support?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rust 1.51.0 does not have specialization of any kind. If I'm reading [the specialization RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md#interaction-with-lifetimes) correctly, then lifetime specialization will **not** be supported even when the RFC is implemented:

> A hard constraint in the design of the trait system is that dispatch
> cannot depend on lifetime information. In particular, **we both cannot,
> and should not allow specialization based on lifetimes**:
>
> - We can't, because when the compiler goes to actually generate code ("trans"), lifetime information has been erased -- so we'd have no
>   idea what specializations would soundly apply.
> - We shouldn't, because lifetime inference is subtle and would often lead to counterintuitive results. For example, you could easily fail
>   to get `'static` even if it applies, because inference is choosing the
>   smallest lifetime that matches the other constraints.

(Emphasis mine)

There's some examples further in the link that indicate some of the concrete issues.

I recommend using a `Cow` to handle the "owned or borrowed" case.

Answer (score -1):

I write this answer after reading this [duplicated post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50159002/different-implementations-for-static-and-non-static-arguments) asking how to define a method/function that behaves differently when it is passed a static string or a non-static string.

This is not possible, so a workaround may be using a wrapper type to wrap the string argument in an `enum`:

```
enum MyString {
    Static(&'static str),
    Heap(String),
}

fn bar(arg: &MyString) {
    match arg {
        &MyString::Static(ref name) => println!("my first pc was {}", name),
        &MyString::Heap(ref name) => println!("I dont know {}", name),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = Vec::new();

    let forever: &'static str = "zx-spectrum";
    let local: &str = &"commodore64".to_string();

    v.push(MyString::Static(forever));

    // ERROR: try to insert 'a lifetime
    // v.push(Mystring::Static(local));
    v.push(MyString::Heap(local.to_string()));

    v.push(MyString::Heap("muggle".to_string()));

    bar(&v[0]);
    bar(&v[1]);
}
```

`MyString` stores a statically-allocated string literal as a `&'static str` and all other strings as a `String`.

As pointed in the comments below, the standard library provides a type that fits the borrowed/owned case: the smart pointer [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html).

The enum `MyString` used in this example is just a specific enum for managing string types.

The only difference stems from a somewhat more specific naming of the enum and its variants related to the specific usage: `MyString::Static("forever")` versus `Cow::Borrowed("forever")` and `MyString::Heap(str)` versus `Cow::Owned(str)`.

Does this help improve mnemonics and code readability? I'm quite sure that this holds only for novices or occasional Rust programmers, not for seasoned Rustaceans.