# Different implementations for static and non-static arguments

Tags: rust, lifetime

I would like a method, accepting a `&str`, to behave differently when it is passed a static string or a non-static string (the motivation is that the static string does not need to be copied, while the non-static string may die too soon, so I need to copy it).

I don't know if the compiler can do that for me, and if yes, how to code it properly. All my attempts result in "conflicting implementations", as in [this example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ae075385d18bbe99f7b897d8fd86c10d&version=stable&mode=debughttps://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ae075385d18bbe99f7b897d8fd86c10d&version=stable&mode=debug).

```
struct Foo;

trait Bar<'a, 'b> {
    fn bar(&'a self, &'b str);
}

impl<'a> Bar<'a, 'static> for Foo {
    fn bar(&'a self, _: &'static str) {
        println!("STATIC");
    }
}

impl<'a, 'b> Bar<'a, 'b> for Foo
where
    'b: 'a,
{
    fn bar(&'a self, _: &'b str) {
        println!("NON-STATIC");
    }
}

fn main() {
    Foo {}.bar("hello"); // display "STATIC"
    let world = String::from("world");
    Foo {}.bar(&world); // display "NON-STATIC"
}
```

If this can't be done with generics, could it be done with a macro?

Comment: This question has already been asked: [Is it possible to specialize on a static lifetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37053567/155423). Please [edit] your question to explain why it's different. Otherwise, we can mark this as already answered.

Comment: just posted, give a look it this fit your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50168450/3356777

Comment: it is indeed a duplicate. Sorry about that, and thanks for pointing to the answers.